# How to make a reference to object with C++

Tags: c++, oop

Like if I have some classes like

```
class B {
public:
    int a;
};

class C {
    B reference;
}

B Test;
C Test2;

C.reference = Test;

B.a = 2;
```

And now I'd need to get 2 also from C.reference.a

Comment: I think the answer is in your question : use a reference to B in class C ( B& instead of B) but you need to initialize it in the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
class C {
public:
    B& reference; // notice use of '&' to denote a reference

    C(B& ref) : reference(ref)
    {
    }
};
```

And it would be used like this:

```
C Test2 = C(Test);
```

Comment: you should explain the pitfalls of references.

Answer (score 1):

```
class C {
public:
    C(B & ref)
        :reference(ref)
    {}

    B & reference;
};

B Test;
C Test2(Test);
```

Note that if you have a reference member, the compiler will not generate an assignment operator for you, so you can't do this:

```
B b1, b2;
C c1(b1), c2(b2);
c1 = c2; // can't do this
```

You can of course still provide your own.  If you want to be able to reassign the reference, then you can use a pointer, and you should probably make it private and use accessors to read and modify the data.

Comment: yyou should explain the pitfalls of reference members.